# How safe is this query method

Tags: php, mysql

If we can't use PDO or mysqli (for any reason), is this method safe for INSERT and SELECT?

```
<?php

  if (!empty($_POST[id]) && !empty($_POST[name])) {
    require_once ( 'config.php' );

    // SAFE INTVAL ID
    $id = intval($_POST[id]);

    $connect = mysql_connect("$server", "$user", "$password")
    OR die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("$database", $connect);

    // ESCAPING NAME
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[name]);

    $query = "INSERT INTO table (id, name) VALUES ('$id', '$name')";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $connect);

    if (!$result) { echo 'success'; } else { echo 'fail'; }
  }

?>
```

cause i've read many times never to use mysql_query, 
is it dangerous even if we are careful and escape in time?

Comment: mysql_query is not necessarily dangerous, but deprecated and will be removed in future. There must never be a reason not to choose PDO or mysqli imo. If you need a review of your code, please refer to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "Safe" is a relative term.  Exploitable bugs have previously been discovered in `mysql_real_escape_string()`, and other undiscovered ones could still be lurking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my knowledge, your query is perfectly fine.
You are escaping the SQL with

```
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[name])
```

This adds  additional security to your code.
The only suggestion is that use:

```
$_POST['name']
```

instead of

```
$_POST[name]
```

As it will generate PHP warning.

Thanks.

Comment: I dont think so for your additional security comments, check this ->http://codepad.org/WVamm85G

Comment: thanks, thats because i need to use a variable inside my $_POST like $_POST[$var] , any suggestions for that?

Comment: @swapnesh What about you [enable error reporting](http://codepad.org/DN6ZVe8R) so you see PHP will try to be smart and is looking for a constant. And if that cannot be found converts the constant to a string. :)

Comment: @PeeHaa yeah very true..as after testing it in codepad i just switched to my local to test with error reporting on ...very thanks for correcting me..although i am keeping both my comments here just for the future reference.. and this is how i learn from Stacks..really nice to learn a lot from u people :)

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers, it's "safe", as in the query can't be exploited. The one thing to watch out for though is that you're trusting your users to provide you with an ID (which I assume here is your primary key). Of course, this means that your users can overwrite other records.

A better way would be to omit the id column (and its value) from your query, and mark the column as AUTO_INCREMENT when creating the table. Any omitted value from a query becomes its default value, which in this case will *normally* be the last value of `id`+1.

Comment: thank you, id and name are already created in database, that's why i have to get it, but i have a check which uses SELECT to check if user exists

Comment: Fair enough, just ensure that the user cannot overwrite anything with the query.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you say you can't use them, possibly because they're too complicated (?), you really should doing a little research and understanding how to use them. I promise that once you do, you won't even want to go back! :) I recommend using PDO / MySQLi because PHP 5.5 is depreciating MySQL and you'll get E_DEPRECIATED notices.

Prepared statements using MySQLi or PDO mean that you don't have to escape any strings, you simply refer to each variable with a `?`, and then state later on what datatype the ? has `s` being string, for example.

You wouldn't need to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` then. Future proof your code! :)